# Changing automatic URL alias

Tags: nodes, uri

I am populating a new site with my old site's content (i.e copying it) and wanted to make sure all the URLs will be the same. At the momement my old path is name.com/work/sony-folklore and and the new one is: name.building-site.com/content/sony.

NOTE: *name.com and name.building-site.com are dummy names that refer to the live and the development version of the site.*

What can I change to make the CMS generate the same URLs as they did in the old site?

Thanks

Comment: is the old site also powered by drupal?

Comment: example.com exists for this very reason. RFC 2606 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the alias by editing a content. See the screenshot below to edit url alias.

[image]